# Renaming some files from input folder to an output folder using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using two folders one is for inuput folder where all files are exist and the other is an output folder where the renamed files are to be saved.

Please see below for the code. I'm using Str() function to convert a numeric value but it's not working. why I do not know. Also i'm not getting the required out put.

I am facing problem i.e Str(m) not WORKING and shows type mismatching Error

Please help.....

```
Sub ChangeFilename()


IFILEPATH = InputBox("Copy INPUT folder PATH")
OFILEPATH = InputBox("Copy OUTPUT folder PATH")
Dim strfile As String
Dim filenum As String

strfile = Dir(IFILEPATH)
startFile = InputBox("Start File NAME")
endFile = InputBox("End File NAME")
Dim r as Long
r = InputBox("Input INCREAMENT valu")
Do While strfile <> ""
 If (strfile = startFile) Then

  Do While strfile <= endFile
    x = Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)
    x = Right(x, Len(x) - 2)
    y = Val(x)
    If y > 0 Or y < 9 Then
      Dim m As Long
      m = y + r
      Dim k As String
     'MsgBox Str(m)
      k = Str(m)        //This is the area where I am facing problem i.e Str(m) not WORKING and shows type mismatching Error
      x = "00" & k
      Name IFILEPATH & strfile As OFILEPATH & "eq" & x & ".eps"
    ElseIf y >= 9 Or y < 99 Then
      m = y + r
      x = "0" & k
      Name IFILEPATH & strfile As OFILEPATH & "eq" & x & ".eps"
    Else
      'x = Str(Val(x + r))
      Name IFILEPATH & strfile As OFILEPATH & "eq" & x & ".eps"

    End If
  Loop
 End If
  strfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to do, but it doesn't look like you've set the `r`as an integer, so it's only using the value as a string.  If you're trying to get it to increment, then I assume you'd want it to be a numerical value, as opposed to just text.

I believe you need to add this dimension to the top:

```vba
Dim r As Long
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you're going to want to place something like this in one of the loops

```vba
r = r + 1
```

That will make it increment the value of `r` during each loop.  If you want the increment to be the same as what the user entered, you would need something a little more elaborate because it would  need to hold the original value or `r`.  You could use `r2 = r` towards the beginning (after the user input) so that you could use `r2` as the increment (which would be the original `r` value).  Then you could use:

```vba
r = r + r2
```

Don't forget to dimension the `r2` at the beginning:

```vba
Dim r2 As Long
```